# How can I set dark mode for Word documents

Tags: macos, ms-office, color, dark-mode

Microsoft recently released the Dark Mode for MS Office for Mac. While the Dark Mode sets the interface to dark color palette, the page area itself still remains white and the text is black.

How can I set the page to dark mode, i.e. dark page area and light font color?

Or does keeping the page area white follow some kind of Apple design guidelines? But again, in BBEdit you can select a theme with dark background and light text.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a new template file:

```
File -> New Document
```

click on `Design` tab then click on `Page Color` icon and select `More Colors`.
There, you can use a color picker to sample you favorite color (I picked `#282a36` in the Dracula theme in BBEdit) and set this color as your page color. 
And after that, select

```
File -> Save as Template
```

and then `Save`. 
From now on, when you open Word, select

```
File -> New from Template
```

and select your template.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you print such a document? Does is still print black text on white background?

Comment: @nohillside Good question. Just printed it and it printed black text on white paper. Same as saving as PDF - black on white.